# Reading UIImage data while scrolling, pros and cons

Tags: ios, uitableview, caching, uiimage, nsfilemanager

I'm doing some sort of scroller for some images i've saved on the device using `NSFileManager`,

Everytime the user scrolls into the specific cell i read the image data and load it, and the scrolling is a bit slow and choppy,

Currently to read an image from the disk i use `[NSFileManager contentsAtPath: myFile]` and then `[UIImage imageWithData: imageData]` .

I wanted to know if theres an easier and more efficient way to do this , 
I thought of just preloading the images into memory, but these images are 700x700 pixels each and i'm afraid it would cause over-memory usage,

Anyways, i also saw on some other thread that JPG Representations seem to take up a lot more memory than PNG, so after changing everything to PNG , it seemed to be working a bit better, but still not fast enough.

Would love to hear from your experiences :)
Shai.

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Comment: I think I ended up loading the image data on a separate thread with GCD (Grand Central Dispatch), letting the UI work smoothly on the mainthread while the data is being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a [lazy image loading example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) that can get you started loading images from local or network locations.

Comment: That examples seems to provide only techniques for remote-data fetching, which i'm already familiar with ... Or i'm missing something? Thanks for your answer Eric ! :)

Comment: When passing in the URL of the file, instead of using NSURL URLWithString:, use fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:.

Comment: Thanks Eric, ill check it out tomorrow morning first thing :)

Comment: It seems they're lazy-loading, but saving every icon loaded in an array of objects, which is exactly what i don't want to do, since they're handling 88x88 icons, its not a problem, but i'm handling 700x700 images so I have to make sure i'm only loading the currently viewed cells and not keeping the rest in the memory.. It needs some more messing arround. Ill wait for more answers and if i won't get anything better by the evening ill mark yours as correct. Thanks for the kind help :)

Comment: I would only use the Apple sample code as a guideline, specifically, the part where the images are not loaded until the scrolling stops.  I had a similar project not too long ago, where we were using Core Data as the data source.  We would fault out the images when we didn't need them to keep memory down.